# how to burn hex file to pic ? "hardware"

Tags: pic, pic18, pic32, pic24

**Good evening ..**

*I'm new in the microcontroller ..*

I have studied a course on "pic 16" and As I knew the pic16 needs an external device to burn hex file in rom .

Now I want to study the pic24 And I found something called usb in pic24 ..

Can I burn the hex file without an external device via a usb ?? Or this is another term has not related to burning hex file ??

Is there a way to burn the file without an additional device ??

And also in the pic32  Are there any types of it can be directly connected without the use kit3 ??

I do not want to buy kit3 :\

Is the kit3 can Programming all kinds pic microcontroller (16,24,32) ??

Sorry for extension

and Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The PIC32 starter kits have a debugger/programmer built in. Otherwise there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can burn a hex file without an external device via USB.  The term to look for is “Bootloader”.  Many Microchip devices can allocate and protect a section of memory for bootload firmware providing the means to self-program.

If you’re buying a demo board with a bootloader pre-installed (and as long as you don’t over-write the bootloader) you can upload hexfiles and run them without an external programmer. But if you build your own board you’ll need a programmer at least once to load the bootload code.

And yes, the PICkit 3 can be used to program a wide variety of Microchip devices. The document *Device Support.htm* in the release notes of MPLAB X has a matrix of devices and programmers.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately i've never used pic24 family, but if you're going to try pic32 try to take a look here:

[pic32-avrdude-bootloader](https://github.com/chipKIT32/PIC32-avrdude-bootloader)

It works with avrdude, the same bootloader used by Arduino boards and it's not much hard to use properly. I don't know if there's a way to use also serial monitor via usb, but if you debug with mplabx you don't need it

Ciao!